# SQL: Can we make query to compare data for 2 different years in same month, but looking at the same day as priority

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query

FYI: I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Because scope of the function is a selling date which is different by the days of week (like comparison for customer visiting percentage).

So the main key to compare between last-this year, is to check the same week or same day that most related to the month and are same day (Monday, Tuesday, ...)

[image: 2018-November] [image: 2017-November]

For example:

```
2018/11/01 should compare to 2017/11/02 (Thu)
2018/11/02 should compare to 2017/11/03 (Fri)
...
2018/11/30 should compare to 2017/12/01 (Fri)
```

I can't imagine the syntax out of my head.
What is syntax should I write?
What are the keywords, functions should I call to achieve this scope?

Anyone who has experience about some kind of function like this, please help.
All comments would be appreciate.

Comment: Apologized, I didn't know that the specific product be related that much.
I'm using `SQL Server - Web 64 bit v.11.0.6020.0 => 2012`

Comment: Would `2018/10/31` compare to `2017/11/01`? Where is the base logic for comparing? Possibly: `Week Number` + `Weekday`?

Comment: @hot2use Should comparing start from `2018/11/01` to `2018/11/30` (scope on the month that is focusing) and look like the `Week Number AND Weekday` will approach what I aim. Thanks for your guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can use two (ore more) ways but both are related with [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
DECLARE @Date1 datetime = '20181101';
DECLARE @Date2 datetime = '20170101';

SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date1) DayOfYear,
       DATEPART(WEEK, @Date1) WeekNumber,
       DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date1) WeekDay,
       @@DATEFIRST FirstDayOfWeek;

DayOfYear | WeekNumber | WeekDay | FirstDayOfWeek
--------: | ---------: | ------: | :-------------
      305 |         44 |       5 | 7
```

**Using DayOfYear**

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date1), @Date2) AS UsingDayOfYear;

| UsingDayOfYear      |
| :------------------ |
| 02/11/2017 00:00:00 |
```

**Using same week & same day of week**

This depends on [first day of week](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEPART(WEEK, @Date1) - 1) * 7) + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date1), @Date2) UsingSameMonthSameDayOfWeek;

UsingSameMonthSameDayOfWeek |
| :-------------------------- |
| 02/11/2017 00:00:00         |
```

You can use that function to add another combination, for example: First Thursday of November.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=23b32ebd12f312493df0151f23daf072)*

Comment: Thanks, it seem I got a clue from your answer, then I can solve this. So I would prefer the `Week Number AND Day of Week` method, because when I write the syntax, it become more natural sentence than `DayOfYear` method.

Comment: I'm glad to help.